# How can I handle SIGINT in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, handler, signals, sigint

I know how to create custom signal handlers in Java, Python, Ruby, Perl, and Lisp, thanks to Google and a plethora of tutorials. I can't find online how to create handlers for SIGINT, SIGTERM, HUP, etc. in Erlang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not. OS signals handled exclusively by Erlang VM. I guess OS signals can be handled in a driver but it can interfere with the VM signal handler so use it on your own risk.

Comment: I'm sad to hear that, but at least I know that now. I just wish I could save to disk before Control + C threatens my programs.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this: http://erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html#erl_signal_server. I have not seen it formally announced anywhere, but I might have missed the announcement.