# Catch when killed erlang application

Tags: erlang, terminate, erlang-otp

I have erlang application. I run it, it's ok, all normally. When i killed erlang shell with my application with `Ctrl+C`, my application stoped too, it's right behavior all ok, but how can i catch this moment? I need to clear some resources when my application stoped, normaly or with error it does not matter. I try to clean resources in `gen_server:terminate`, but when i killed erlang shell it didn't execute. Where can i catch moment that's my application stoped/killed?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088586/how-can-i-handle-sigint-in-erlang. Also this: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-April/065595.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a `^C` you are not killing the Erlang shell you are killing the whole Erlang system, the whole OS process. So after that all Erlang is dead. What is it you want to do? If you want to take down the whole system in a controlled fashion then use `init:stop/0/1`. It will first stop all the applications and their supervision trees allowing the behaviours to terminate properly.

Comment: in the shell you can also call q().

Comment: Which does the same thing and calls `init:stop`.